# Replacement for deprecated Facebook code for Android

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, deprecated

I want to know the exact replacement for the below code without deprecated code.
Moreover, i want to try it in new Facebook SDK 3.0.

```
Facebook aFacebook = new Facebook("app_id");
if( !aFacebook.isSessionValid() ) {
    aFacebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "email" }, 
                        new LoginDialogListener());
}
```

I tried many thing. But, couldn't get it done.

TIA

Comment: Have you see this page - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/upgrading-from-2.0-to-3.0/

Comment: That should be posted as answer.

Comment: @Gugan, feel free to post the code that solved your problem as an answer and mark your own answer as correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this question has no answer, I am writing one.

In 3.0 Facebook SDK for Android, Session class is used to Login. Initially, as mentioned in the question, the authorize method was used.

The code to serve as exact replacement for the code mentioned in question:

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session == null) {
        session = new Session(getApplicationContext());
    }
Session.setActiveSession(session);
```

Comment: perfect and add this piece of code.

Session.setActiveSession(session);

Comment: Now this answer is also deprecated